# Applescript opens new window for everything when run

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, automator, tweetbot

I have the following code I did for a tweetbot keyboard shortcut to open tweetbot and create a new tweet.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    activate application "Tweetbot 2"
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using command down
    return input
end run
```

However, it always opens a new window for anything that is run in the background as well. This only happens when Tweetbot is not already running.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: It opens a new window of what? AppleScript Editor, Tweetbot?

Comment: Whatever is already running .. Opens a new applescript editor if automator is being used, opens a new safari window if safari is being used etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because the application is not in the foreground.

The `activate` command will not wait the response of the application when the application is not scriptable.
So the script executes immediately the `keystroke` command, therefore the `keystroke` will be intercepted by another application.

> ```
> activate application "Tweetbot 2"
> tell application "System Events"
>   tell process "Tweetbot 2"
>       repeat until exists
>           delay 0.4
>       end repeat
>       set frontmost to true
>       delay 0.2
>       keystroke "n" using command down
>   end tell
> end tell
> ```

Comment: Thank you @jackjr300 , but the code just runs infinitely and does not stop ... it puts tweetbot as the foreground but doesnt really prompt a new tweet ! Can you please explain the commands you have used ?? Im trying to learn how to script using automator

Comment: This is because the process name is not the same as the application.
I don't know any Mac OS X application named "**Tweetbot 2**".
 The name is "**Tweetbot**" on Mac App Store. 

Check the name of your process with this script: `tell application "System Events" to name of processes`, execute it in the editor, look at the result. ---explanation of the commands:
wait until the process exists, put the process to foreground, execute the keystroke.